# Mock javascript function imported from vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to set up tests for a vue component `collector` which is importing a Javascript module to collect some data.

**components/collector.vue**

```
<script>
import dataService from '@/services/dataService.js';
...

dataService.collectResults().then(results => {
  this.data = results;
});
</script>
```

The javascript file:

**services/dataService.js**

```
let dataService = {
    collectResults() {
        [...]
        return dataPromise;
    }
    [...]
} 
export default dataService;
```

I'm using `jest` for the tests for the `collector` component, and trying to mock the `collectResults` method.

**collector.spec.js**

```
jest.mock('dataService');
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import collector from '@/components/collector.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';


describe('behaviour tests', () => {
  let cmp;
  beforeEach(() => {
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    const router = new VueRouter();
    cmp = mount(collector, {
      router
    });

it('dummy test', () => {
  console.log(cmp.vm.data);
}
```

**services/__mocks__/dataService.js**

```
const dataServiceMock = jest.genMockFromModule('dataService');

function __collectResults() {
  return new Promise(() => {
    console.log('mocked!');
    [...]
  });
}

dataServiceMock.collectResults = __collectResults;
export default dataServiceMock;
```

However, when running the tests the original `dataService.js` file is being executed (which in my case leads to an exception).

What should be the correct approach to this case, considering that I've to mock ~10 functions while leaving others as they are?